# Lua+nginx и фаза логирования

Tags: linux, nginx, lua

Каким образом с помощью lua можно перед фазой логирования nginx вырезать некоторые данные из POST запроса. Тоесть конкретно в лог что бы они не попадали. Это к примеру данные карт, поля паролей и т.д. Например если хотим из запроса убрать d = 4:

```
curl --header «Content-Type: application/json» --request POST --data '{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4}' https://127.0.0.1
```

в лог должно записать:

```
'{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3}'
```

Comment: Сформировать для логирования другую переменную, без секретных данных и писать в лог её, а не оригинальную переменную. Хотя обычно пост-запросы в лог вообще не пишут

Comment: я понимаю о чем вы, но задача как раз и стоит в том что бы формировать лог с пост данными как есть - но за исключением некоторых чувствительных к безопасности полей в общей таблице

Comment: зато как весело можно уронить ваш сервер отправив в пост запросе пару гигабайт. пишите лог на бэкэнде лучше..

Comment: client_max_body_size - нет не слышал